Support of LTspice Netlist
I created a netlist using MATLAB scripting.  When i open it directly in LT SPICE, it shows some gibberish characters possibly in Japanese alphabets, but when i open same netlist in some other SPICE say, Tanner it opens perfectly fine. What could be possible reason behind and how to solve this issue?

Hello and welcome.  It would help if you gave a little more information, such as a portion of the netlist, and what operating system you're using.
